# Doubts creating Charts in Excel from Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, charts

I am trying to draw a Chart in a Excel Sheet from Delphi 7. I am using ExcelXp Unit.
For now, I can write text in Sheet cells. I have TExcel Application component in the main form application, called "Excel".
My code for creating the Workbook and write the first Worksheet:

```
  Excel.Connect;
  Excel.Workbooks.Add(NULL,0);
  sheet := Excel.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1];
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    Sheet.Cells[i, 1] := i;
```

Now I need to draw a Chart in same sheet. I searched in Google, but couldn't find anything related. What I got is just the next code of lines that creates a Chart in other sheet:

```
Excel.Workbooks.Item[1].Sheets.add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam,1,xlchart,0);
```

Neither found any API for the components.
Any help please ?

Comment: a helpful method is recording macros in Excel. The content of the macros can be easily transcribed to delphi code.

Comment: @bummi thanks ! i bear in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I found a piece of code in Google Code. This code manipulating charts:
http://khalid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Delphi/Excel%20automation%20example.txt

The charts have a method: "Location()", thas specify where show the chart:

```
chart.Location(xlLocationAsObject,Sheet.Name);
```

In the links shows how change the position of the chart !.